# Is it ok to put a main() function in all modules for the purpose of unit tests?

Tags: java

I have several subclasses to go along with my main class. Is it bad practice to add a main function to every single class for tests?

Comment: Yes, keep your tests separate from your application.

Comment: This scale badly and enclose code in your application you do not need.  Tests are separate from shipped code.

Comment: why is everyone downvoting, it's just a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to add a main function to every single class for tests?

Yes, for various reasons:

- It suggests you've got a single test per class, or multiple tests within a single method.
- It suggests you're probably not using a unit test framework, with all the built-in helpers (and runners) available
- Combining your test code and your production code makes it harder to find your tests *and* harder to read your production code.

Typically, I use a separate Eclipse project in the same package (for access to package-restricted members), using JUnit or something similar.